# How to add navigation drawer feature in later views(for ex: 2nd view) of the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement Navigation Drawer like menu on my iPhone project.
I have looked at the forums and find out there are many samples given in this link:
[Stackoverflow Navigation drawer query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775195/splitview-like-facebook-app-on-iphone)

But, they have not helped me much. Because, all the apps are developed Navigation drawer in the Home screen(1st view) of the app itself and using `window.rootViewController`

My requirement is, I need Navigation Drawer like menu NOT in the home screen(1st view) of the app, rather need on the 2nd view of the app, hence I don't know how to add this feature.

Could someone please suggest me how to add navigation drawer like menu feature in later views(for ex: 2nd view) of the app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get how you want the menu. You can add Navigation Controller anywhere you want, all it's going to do is give you a Navigation Bar on which you can give a title and a Back button, usually with the name of the title of the previous page.

You can simply add the navigation where you want and control drag from the view or object you want to perform the segue. If it's a button you can use an IBAction with a performSegueWithIdentifier method.

Hope I could help

Comment: Hi, I am talking about "Navigation Drawer" like menu, the other term could be "Split view" kind of view, Not the navigation controller.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, Stella. Misunderstood your goal. Give me a moment and I see if I can help

Comment: Not sure if it's of great help but, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326428/uisplitviewcontroller-doesnt-work-on-iphone5-nor-6