# Open UISplitViewController to Master View rather than Detail

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split-view interface with a target iPhone 6 application. On the first launch of the application, it opens to the Detail View; I would like it to open to the Master View. I have tried:

```
self.splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.PrimaryOverlay
```

Which was suggested elsewhere [(Prior StackOverFlow Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849654/uisplitviewcontroller-display-master-view-above-detail-in-portrait-orientation) but it doesn't seem to do anything, and does not open the Master view on launch.  I also tried to add the following line to my AppDelegate:

```
splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:
```

But despite returning true or false ([Another Prior Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master)) I had no success.

I did launch up the example Master-Detail application in Xcode, and it loads to the Master view based on the splitViewController: call returning false; however, I'm not sure how to make this work in a more complicated layout.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

### Swift

[UISplitViewController display master view above detail in portrait orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849654/uisplitviewcontroller-display-master-view-above-detail-in-portrait-orientation) is not about showing the Master view, it is about presenting the Detail view in full width, underneath the Master view.

[UISplitViewController in portrait on iPhone shows detail VC instead of master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master) is about the principle of the collapse mechanism.

This present answer addresses:

- **Master → Detail** *(Compact width)*

  - iPhone 4s, 5, 5s, SE, 6, 6s, 7 (any orientation)
  - iPod Touch
  - any iPhone Plus (portrait)
- **side-by-side** *(all other sizes)*

  - iPad
  - any iPhone Plus (landscape)

You must set `preferredDisplayMode`. You would want is *`.primaryVisible`* if it existed! Using `.allVisible`, iOS picks `Detail` if only 1 view fits *(Compact width)*; in that size, the code below will pick `Master`.

The trick is to change *both* the `preferredDisplayMode` to `.allVisible` *and* to return `true` in `collapseSecondary:onto`.

```swift
class PrimarySplitViewController: UISplitViewController,
                                  UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }

    func splitViewController(
             _ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
             collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
             onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        // Return true to prevent UIKit from applying its default behavior
        return true 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: That, sir, is awesome and helped me out too.

Comment: I edited and left in the older code in case anyone needs it.

Comment: ...making Stack Overflow a better place!

Comment: Fantastic solution :-)

Comment: iOS 13 calls the delegate functions only on transitions, and ignores preferredDisplayMode in compact sizes. To switch to Master View or **open** with it on compact sizes (portrait on all iPhones, landscape on SE), you need to add `navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: @pommy - add this in the viewDidLoad in PrimarySplitViewController class as per the example?

Comment: @MihaiL I added it in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Side note: no need to subclass `UISplitViewController`, it's possible to access it via `window.rootViewController` in `AppDelegate` and make necessary changes there.

Answer (score 28):

### iOS 14

I wasn't getting a callback for `splitViewController(_:collapseSecondary:onto:)` and instead used the following new method.

```
func splitViewController(_ svc: UISplitViewController, topColumnForCollapsingToProposedTopColumn proposedTopColumn: UISplitViewController.Column) -> UISplitViewController.Column {
    return .primary
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on iOS 14. Thanks.  If you're looking to support earlier iOS versions, add `@available(iOS 14.0,*)` on the line above the function

Answer (score 13):

**Step 1** - Open MasterViewController

**Step 2** - ensure the table view has the UISplitViewControllerDelegate protocol. Eg:

```
class ListVC: UITableViewController,UISplitViewControllerDelegate {}
```

**Step 3** - Add it in ViewDidLoad

```
splitViewController?.delegate = self
```

**Step 4** - Then override this method to say the master view controller should always collapse onto the detail view controller:

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> On the first launch of the application, it opens to the Detail View; I would like it to open to the Master View

Assuming you want that only on the first launch, but not always; for example in the case that the Master View shows an empty data set; then the solution is just as the Master-Detail template shows:

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
    guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
    if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
        // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**iOS 14**

From [WWDC 2020 - Build for iPad](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10105/), You can add a specific view controller for the compact width class (e.g. iPhone in portrait, iPad in Slide Over) by checking **Use Separate View Controller** in the Attribute Inspector of SplitViewController.

[image]

So you can set any view controller as an initial view controller as you want by setting relationship segue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Tried this approach; it's finding `nil` when I attempt to access the detail view controller to update anything.

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 14 -- Two Column Mode Updates**

I struggled with this for a while before eventually finding that the Split View Controller has been reworked in iOS14, so none of the answers above are relevant anymore.

I'd recommend starting with this article [here](https://www.biteinteractive.com/split-view-controllers-done-right-in-ios-14/).

But in case you are looking for a quick fix:

- You'll need to set the "compact view controller" relationship on your Split View Controller. You can do this by right-clicking the Split View Controller and dragging a new relationship to the view controller you would like to display in compact mode.
- My app has a TableView, and in compact mode I want to push a Detail View Controller when a cell is tapped. In the new iOS 14 SplitView Controller, this has to be done manually. I did this by adding the following to my `didSelectRowAt` function:

```swift
        // If we are in compact mode, we need to push the detail view controller
        if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
            if splitViewController.isCollapsed {
                let shipmentDetailViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "shipmentDetailViewController") as! ShipmentDetailViewController
                shipmentDetailViewController.shipment = selectedShipment
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(shipmentDetailViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Works on Xcode 13.0. None of other answer works.

Comment: Finally, this one works! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is an oldish question and none of the answers were for Objective C, and even when I ported the Swift answers, none worked for me.  One was close, by @SwiftArchitect.

But he recommended setting the content mode to `.allVisible` (`UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible` in Objective C) - this makes the master view display all the time, splitting the view into master on one side, detail on the other.  Which is kinda cool, but the OP asked specifically to display the master view on initial launch, which is what I needed to do.

The change was to use `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay` for the display mode.

This answer is for Xcode 9.4.1, deployment target 11.4.

Here is MasterViewController.h - you need to add UISplitViewControllerDelegate in the protocols declaration:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "MasterDetailDemo+CoreDataModel.h"

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
<UISplitViewControllerDelegate,
NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController<Event *> *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

And then in your MasterViewController.m, you need to set the split view controller delegate and the content mode in ViewDidLoad, and following along with @SwiftArchitect's answer, to also add the split view controller delegate method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // needed to "slide out" MasterView on startup on iPad
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
    self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

// split view delegate method
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    return true;
}
```

**NOTE**:  After some testing, I found that the split view delegate method and the split view protocol was not necessary.  Without it, it appears to work exactly the same.  Perhaps this is a result of changes in iOS since the question was originally asked and answered.

I got it working fine just by putting this line in my ViewDidLoad method:

```
self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just inherit from `UISplitViewController` and use this new class in the storyboard (based on SwiftArchitect's answer):

```
class MasterShowingSplitViewController :UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
    }

    func splitViewController(
        _ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
        collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
        onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        // Return true to prevent UIKit from applying its default behavior
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5**, iOS 13

I found other answers useful, but not-quite-there in that they produced the behavior I wanted on iPad or iPhone, but not both.

The solution below is what I used for:

iPhone: Master view always appears first

iPad Portrait: detail always appears, but with master overlaying it; detail is full-screen (not just right-of-master)

iPad Landscape: Master always on left, detail always on right

```
class RootSplitViewController: UISplitViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            self.preferredDisplayMode = .automatic
        }
        else {
            self.preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible
        }
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension RootSplitViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
                             collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController,
                             onto primaryViewController:UIViewController)
        -> Bool
    {
        // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return true
        // Or: return false if your application logic makes this appropriate
        // return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have this error :"Cannot find 'AppState' in scope". How can I fix it ?

Comment: Irazza, I altered the code so it compiles stand alone. The intent was to understand the logic and apply to your situation, but if you're trying to literally just copy and paste code without understanding how it works then this version would let you do that. But it may not be right for your situation.