# UISplitViewController hide master view on iPad landscape

Tags: ios, ipad

I want to show displayModeButtonItem on iPad. I have this code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
```

It works great on iPhone 6+.
[image: iphone 6+]

But not that well on iPad Landscape.
[image: ipad landscape]

Help!!!

Comment: Try setting the split controller's preferredDisplayMode to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden` or one of the other values.

Comment: Would this answer be of relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29873271/218152

Comment: @rmaddy .PrimaryHidden is better where I see the back button, but I want the master view to be open initially

Comment: @SwiftArchitect .AllVisible also leaves it open the Master View in iPad Portrait. I would like it to slide over in iPad Portrait.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UISplitViewController, and implement delegate

```
class PrimarySplitViewController: UISplitViewController,
                                  UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func splitViewController( _ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, 
collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, 
onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true 
    }
}
```