# Swift/IOS: Master-Detail template always goes to Detail view on iphone - Landscape mode, during startup

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I know this is an old issue and had been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master) in objective C. But i am looking for solution in Swift. My code for splitviewController in  AppDelegate is as follows.

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController!) -> Bool {
      if let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController {
          if let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DocumentsViewController {
              if topAsDetailController.tracksDocumentTableView == nil {
                  // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
                  return true
              }
          }
      }
      return false
  }
```

i've got two views (MAster-Detail) as MasterViewController and DocumentViewConttoller. Is this a bug? or am i missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty much like mine and mine is working fine. When you are checking

`if topAsDetailController.tracksDocumentTableView == nil`

are you setting the value of `tracksDocumentTableView` in `prepareForSegue` of the master view controller?