# Why splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController: is not called on iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus

I implemented subclass of `UISplitViewController` in my app for both: `iPhone` and `iPad`. Method mentioned in title is called when I rotate device from `Landscape` to `Portrait` orientation. It works really nice unless I run the app on iPhone 6 Plus. Why this method is not called there?

What to do to make this method work?

When I start the app on `iPhone 6 Plus` everything is fine in both orientations. But the problem is when I rotate `iPhone 6 Plus` from `Landscape` to `Portrait`. My navigation controller is not gonna work as it is expected.

This is what I mean:

**iPhone 5s Portrait**
[image]

**iPhone 5s Portrait when I select location**

[image]

**iPhone 5s Landscape with selected location**

[image]

**iPhone 5s when I rotate from Landscape to Portrait**

[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus Portrait**

[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus Portrait when I select location**

[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus Landscape with selected location**

[image]

**iPhone 6 Plus when I rotate from Landscape to Portrait** `this is a problem` because my method `splitViewController:collapseSecondaryViewController:ontoPrimaryViewController:` is not called. `UINavigationController` at that time is not working. When I select location nothing happens.

[image]

```
class PBOSplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
        delegate = self
    }

    func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController!, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController!) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

I setup my SplitViewController in Storyboard.

Comment: I tried to force splitViewController to call this method, but it didn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iPhone 6+ has a larger screen and in some ways is treated like an iPad. A split view controller on an iPhone 6+ will try to display both master and detail panes similarly as on an iPad, unless the application is in "Zoomed Display Mode".

NSHipster has an article explaining this in greater detail: http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

Comment: I still don't know how to solve the problem. Is it possible to keep the same behaviour on iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk try forcing the layout you want with UISplitViewControllers `preferredDisplayMode` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/preferredDisplayMode

Comment: I did this also, but it is still not working properly. I think this is a problem with "Zoomed Display Mode" as you said, but there is no such option in Simulator.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk from your updated answer and your comment it is not clear what is not working and what is expected. Please try to be a little more specific.

Comment: I updated the answer with screenshots. Can you look at? Thank you.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk by default split view controller will only show the side by side view on iPhone 6+ (and tablets), and it will remain in detail view after rotating to portrait mode. So I am guessing this has something to do with your customisations. Post the code you are using to setup and edit the split view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75813/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-mrnickbarker).