# Split view controller segue and connections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm building an app in which a part of the app should list all the shops in our town and show some details about them. This part works, but it relies on a split view controller, as you can see in these [pictures](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66972SsSRztRUxtQ3hScTFBcDQ) . I also added a video of the problem.

I didn't know how to use the split view controller, really.. So what i did was the following: I set the split view controller as the initial view controller, and connected the navigation controller which should open up first as the detail view controller. The first navigation controller of the table view is set as master view controller.

The problem now is that when i start the app, i arrive at the homepage (which is good, check the video in the drive), but in the upper left corner, you can see that there is a navigation button to the table view. Is there a way to delete that button, and make my homepage navigation controller the initial view controller again?

I guess I'd have to link the split view controller differently, set the first view controller to initial view controller again, and add a segue to the split view controller, but i don't know what that segue should look like or how I should program it. There's a segue to the first view controller of the table view right now.

In my homepage view controller, this is the code for the segue pushing to the first view controller of my table view right now:

```
func pushRegisterViewShoppen()
{

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueShoppen", sender: self)
}

let shoppen = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

        shoppen.setTitle("Shoppen", forState: .Normal)
        shoppen.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        shoppen.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pushRegisterViewShoppen),
                          forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        let BergStraatFoto = UIImage.init(named: "Bergstraat")
        shoppen.setBackgroundImage(BergStraatFoto!, forState: .Normal)
        tempView.addSubview(shoppen)
```

This is the prepareForSegue in the tableViewController:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let winkel: Winkel
            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                winkel = filteredWinkels[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                winkel = winkels[indexPath.row]
            }

            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailWinkel = winkel
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            controller.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how i could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you need to clearly understand how UISplitViewController works on the iPhone. The home navigation page which has the UITableView is the master right?

Comment: Yes, I don't really know how it works... Indeed, that one's the master, I updated the pictures in the drive they now show which one's the master, detail, relations and the ShoppenSegue

Comment: you should stop the default selection from happening

Comment: Roisers please see answer have update with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this UISplitViewController's delegate method, the detail view controller gets displayed as there is not much space in the iPhone's portrait view so you need to override that using the below delegate method.

```
func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController:UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
//handle it efficiently to decide based on certain conditions.        
return true
}
```

Try this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master) which elaborates more on the problem.