# Why sometimes isCollapsed of UISplitViewController is false on iPhone portrait?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

Shouldn't it be always true for iPhone portrait mode? 
The answers here: [UISplitViewController in portrait on iPhone shows detail VC instead of master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master) don't really solve my problem.

Comment: From apple's documentation: "The value of this property is false when the split view controller is capable of displaying both of its child view controllers at the same time, even if it is not showing them both at the moment."

Comment: Yeah but on iPhone portrait mode, which is compact, it's not capable to display both master & detail screens right?

Comment: In my case the value was false until viewDidLayoutSubviews() was called for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

@Klaas comment is right on. I could only observe the value of `isCollapsed` be meaningful after the view is properly laid out and added to the view hierarchy with a proper trait collection.
In my case moving logic that depended on `isCollapsed` from `viewWillAppear` to `viewDidAppear` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `isCollapsed` was `false` even after `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

I ended up checking if the view controller's `traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass` was equal to `.unspecified`, then I know that `isCollapsed` is not ready to use yet.

You can then watch for changes on the traitCollection. In my case, I needed to know when `horizontalSizeClass` is `.regular`, so the following code did it:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 14, I've found it's required to check if the view has been added to a window (`self.view.window != nil`) before trusting `isCollapsed`.