# UISplitViewController Start with Master View instead of detailView

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

app is starting in detailViewController instead of MasterViewController.
how to fix that in the iPhone?
(its a universal app, and don't want changes when it runs in the iPad)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "embedseg" {

        guard let splitViewController = segue.destination as? UISplitViewController,
        let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
        let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
        let rightNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController,
        let detailViewController = rightNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController

        else { fatalError() }

        let firstMonster = masterViewController.monsters.first
        detailViewController.monster = firstmonster

        masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController

        detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem


    }
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to have the app start initially in a different view controller, have you tried setting the entry point to the `masterViewController` in Storyboard?

Comment: thats not the problem because the NavigationController is inside a Container View

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master