# Show Master on UISplitViewController by Default

Tags: xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

When I create a new "Master Detail App" with Visual Studio for Mac (v8.4.5), the default behavior of the `UISplitViewController` is to show the *Detail* page first when it appears on an iPhone in Portrait mode.

I would rather (as I think most people would rather) have the *Master* page show by default. In my case, the Master page is a table view that holds a list of contacts.

This question is similar to: [UISplitViewController in portrait on iPhone shows detail VC instead of master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master) but for Xamarin.iOS

Similar to the solutions suggested there, I have attempted to assign a delegate without success:

```
    public class ContactsSplitViewControllerDelegate : UISplitViewControllerDelegate
    {
        public override bool EventShowViewController(UISplitViewController splitViewController, UIViewController vc, NSObject sender)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool EventShowDetailViewController(UISplitViewController splitViewController, UIViewController vc, NSObject sender)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public partial class ContactsSplitViewController : UISplitViewController
    {
        public ContactsSplitViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.Delegate = new ContactsSplitViewControllerDelegate();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, it seems that overriding `CollapseSecondViewController` on the delegate will work though I'm not yet convinced it's the proper solution.

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace MasterDetailTest
{
    public class SplitViewControllerDelegate : UISplitViewControllerDelegate
    {
        public override bool CollapseSecondViewController(UISplitViewController splitViewController, UIViewController secondaryViewController, UIViewController primaryViewController)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public partial class MainPageSplitViewController : UISplitViewController
    {
        public MainPageSplitViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            this.Delegate = new SplitViewControllerDelegate();
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // When implemented in my project, I found I needed to set this
            // or the delegate would not be called.
            this.SetNeedsFocusUpdate();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `PreferredDisplayMode`

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.PreferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible;
}
```

Comment: No joy. Still gives the detail page.